# iOS: Setup a View on iPhone 8 and iPhone 8 plus screens

Tags: xcode, ios-autolayout

I have a custom cell nib that I want it to fit both iPhone 8 and iPhone 8 plus screens. I'm only able to make it fit one or the other but not both. I want to make the view width equals 414 for the plus and 375 for the normal, so I decided to use vary for traits, which is not working.

Here is the 8 plus setup: 
[image]

After I click done varying, I set the normal 8 like this
[image]

It is not working. Only If I drag the nib width manually to 375 or 414 then it works for one or the other. For example, if I drag the nib to be 375, then the plus will look like this:
[image]

How do I make this nib fits all screens? I have the collection view with 0 margin constraints on all sides, and the cell size is setup like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

so I don't know why it's acting like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that I was overriding layoutSubviews and leaving it empty.

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
}
```

Just removed it and everything went ok.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create width+height constraints and center imageView, instead hook its sides to its superview. If collection view constraints are set properly and sizeForItemAtIndexPath: returns right value it will do what you want.

Comment: I don't have constraints on width or height, its the nib view that's resizable. I'm not sure what size I should put it in so it fits all screens. I have the cell to cover the whole screen in sizeForItem method. I added it to the question.

Comment: Hook view and Photo ImgV To its superviews with constraints or set autoresizing masks for them. Nib views are not going to resize by themself. If you will not setup constraints views will keep size and position that from nib.I highly doubt that you need to put exact size for PhotoImgView or use sizeClasses for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Use leading, trailing and gives equalWidth to superview and set the multiplier constant according. So it will be adjusted according the screen size. (375 for iPhone 8 and 414 for iPhone 8 plus).
If you want the width to cover whole width , then set the multiplier to 1. And you are done.